# Python data frame :Write Data to csv on the next cell

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I want to write values from a Pandas dataframe to the next immediate cell and not in the first row / column  in  a csv file which looks like:

```
  |column 1| Column2| Column 3| 
  |--------|--------|---------|
  |        |        |         |
  |        |data    | data    |
  |        |data    |data     |
```

I tried ,
pandasdf.iloc[1,1]= pandasdf

But the existing values are getting replaced , is there a way to do this ? Is it possible to create a sql table in this manner ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a single empty row to the top of your existing df. Do this by concating your existing dataframe with a `None` dataframe, putting the `None` fame first

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([None]), df])
```

This creates a new dataframe, where the first row consists only of `None`/`NaN`

Comment: That's working , the column names are still in the first row . Is there an approach for that ?

Comment: when you write, you can choose to set `header=False`, which will not print the header

Comment: Is there a way wherein I could keep the columns ?

Answer (score -1):

just use comma "," to go the next cell "value1,value2" use the "\n" to go to the next row "value1\nvalue2" good luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).